# Rails active_admin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i set routes for controller defined in active_admin gem.

In active_admin, links.rb i have:

```
controller do

    def admin_links

          //some code
    end
end
```

and then i try to do routes for it:

```
scope '/admin_links' do

    put...??
end
```

But i just dont know what controller should i call. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`controller do` is meant to overwrite existing actions.

If you want to add actions, use either `member_action` or `collection_action`.

[Doc is here.](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html)

---

since you use `PUT` verb, you'll have to do:

```
member_action :admin_links, method: 'put' do
  # your action code here
end
```

---